# How to verify that $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$ is a direct sum of the Ue and Uo

Tags: linear-algebra

The $U_e$ and $U_o$ denote the set of all real-valued even/odd function on $\mathbb R$ respectively.

Comment: Which bits are you struggling with? Can you show that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to the functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done the following exercise in matrices? Every matrix is the sum of a symmetric and an anti-symmetric (i.e. $A^T=-A$) matrix.

Define $f_e(x) = \frac12\big(f(x)+f(-x)\big)$ and $f_o(x) = 
\frac12\big(f(x)-f(-x)\big)$. Now $f=f_e+f_o$.  Leave it to you to check the sum is *direct*, that is uniqueness of this expression.